# Cash Flows from Operations in Compustat

Tags: factor-investing

I'm trying to replicate [Piotroski's F-Score](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/p/piotroski-score.asp) (2000) for my PhD. In the paper, one of the components to F-Score is `CFO / Assets` from Compustat. However, item 308 (OANCF) only starts from 1987 and Piotroski's data set starts from 1976. Does anyone know how was cash flow calculated prior to 1987 (or was it derived by subtracting change in working capital from net income)?

Comment: As a first crack you can try to use EBITDA as a proxy for cash-flow from operating activities. Or you can use compustat to build a comprehensive cashflow statement.

Comment: I can see FFO is available from 1971. So I add back change in working capital. I was wondering what Piotroski did as he didn't say what was used before it was available (or whether he's left it blank).

Answer (score 1):

IB-ΔACT+ΔCHE+ΔLCT-ΔDLC+DP

See: Ni (2020, JCF) "Does stakeholder orientation matter for earnings management:
Evidence from non-shareholder constituency statutes"

Comment: Could you please clarify the formula and emphasize how this answers the question?